Orthogonal projection is bounded
Definition: Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. The orthogonal projection of $V$ onto $U$ is the operator $P_U\in L(V)$ given by
$$P_U(u+w)=u$$ if $u\in U, w\in U^{\perp}$.

Let $V$ be a space with inner product and $P\in L(V)$ be an orthogonal projection. Verify that $||P(v)||\leq ||v||$ for all $v\in V$.
So far:
Let $v\in V$. If I write $v$ as $v=v-P(v)+P(v)$, then $||v||^2= \langle v,v \rangle=\langle v-P(x)+P(v),v-P(v)+P(v)\rangle=||v-P(v)||^2+\langle v-P(v),P(v)\rangle +\langle P(v), v-P(v)\rangle +||P(v)||^2$. Now, the result I want clearly holds if $v-P(v)$ is orthogonal to $P(v)$. But how can I rigorously prove this?
$P(v)$ is an orthogonal projection, but is it projecting onto a subspace of $V$? If so, then $v-P(v)$ must be in the orthogonal complement of whichever set $P(v)$ belongs to.

Show your source's definition of "orthogonal projection" first, and start from there.

You are right. $x = P(x) + x - P(x)$ is the unique decomposition of $x$ on $V = \mathrm{Ker}(P) \bigoplus \mathrm{Im}(P)$.

@Zhanxiong I have added the definition of orthogonal projection.  But even with the definition, it remains unclear how to formally prove $\langle x-P(x), P(x)\rangle=0$.

Write $x$ as $u+w, u \in U, w \in U^{\perp}$. $P_U(u+w)=u$ and $(u+w)-P_U(u+w)=(u+w)=u+w-u=w$. And $ \langle u, w \rangle=0$

@geetha290krm Thanks! But why is $(u+w)=u+w -u=w$? Shouldn't it be $(u+w)- P_U(u+w)= (u+w)-u=w ?$

Pythagoras's theorem tells you that $|u + w|^2 = |u|^2 + |w|^2 \ge |u|^2$, where $u$ and $w$ are perpendicular. If you accept that $U + U^\perp = V$, then any $v \in V$ can be expressed as $v = u + w$, where $u \in U$ and $w \in U^\perp$, and so the above is all you need.

There was a typo in my comment.

First you need the fact that $P^*=P$. Indeed,
$$
\langle P^*(u+w),u+w\rangle=\langle u+w,P(u+w)\rangle=\langle u+w,u\rangle=\langle u,u\rangle=\langle u,u+w\rangle=\langle P(u+w),u+w\rangle.
$$
It follows that $P^*=P$.
Now you have $P(v-Pv)=Pv-Pv=0$. So $v-Pv\in\ker P$. Note that $\operatorname{ran}P=U$ by definition, so
$$
\ker P=(\operatorname{ran}P^*)^\perp=(\operatorname{ran}P)^\perp=U^\perp. 
$$
That is, $v-Pv\in U^\perp$.
